# How to get rid of NA when computing the average?

Tags: r

```
b=c(1,4,3,NA)
c=c(NA,4,3,8)
res=(b+c)/2
NA 4 3 NA
```

You can see that whenever we have `NA` the returned result is `NA`. I want to  compute the average between `b and c` if both have values but if either `b or c` has NA then just return the value of `b or c`. The desired results would be:

```
res
1 4 3 8
```

Comment: first of all, use the function `rowMeans`, second use `na.rm=T`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can use `rowMeans`  after `cbind`ing the vectors 'b', 'c' to create a `matrix`.  `rowMeans` have options (`na.rm = TRUE`) to handle `NA` values.

```
rowMeans(cbind(b,c), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Or `colMeans` after `rbind`ing the vectors.

```
colMeans(rbind(b,c), na.rm=TRUE)
```

---

Suppose if we have matrices instead of vectors, we can still do the `rowMeans/colMeans` after looping through the columns/rows of one of the dataset (assuming that they are of the same dimension).  For example,

```
b <- matrix(c(1,4,3, NA, 2, 3, NA, 2), ncol=2)
c <- matrix(c(NA, 4, 3, 8, 1, NA, 3, 4), ncol=2)
```

We loop though the column sequence (`seq_len(ncol(b))`) with `sapply`, `cbind` the corresponding columns of 'b' and 'c' and get the `rowMeans`.  The output will be `matrix` of the same dimension of the initial matrices.

```
m1 <- sapply(seq_len(ncol(b)), function(i)
             rowMeans(cbind(b[,i], c[,i]), na.rm=TRUE))
m1
#   [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1  1.5
#[2,]    4  3.0
#[3,]    3  3.0
#[4,]    8  3.0
```

Another option instead of looping would be to replace the `NA` elements in both datasets with `0`.  We can use `replace` for that, do the `+` and divide based on the count of `NA` elements for each position.

```
m2 <- (replace(b, which(is.na(b)), 0) + replace(c, which(is.na(c)), 0))
m2/(2-(is.na(b)+is.na(c)))
#      [,1] [,2]
#[1,]    1  1.5
#[2,]    4  3.0
#[3,]    3  3.0
#[4,]    8  3.0
```

The above code can be made more compact by using `NAer` from `library(qdap)`

```
library(qdap)
(NAer(b) + NAer(c))/(2-(is.na(b)+is.na(c)))
#  1   2
#1 1 1.5
#2 4 3.0
#3 3 3.0
#4 8 3.0
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun   what if `b` is a matrix and `c` is a matrix. How we can apply your solution?. In fact my real data are matrix but I gave a simple example.

Comment: @temor It depends upon the dimension of `b`.  Can you be a bit more specific?  Suppose if the `nrow(b)` is the same as the `length` of `c`.  Then we can `cbind` both and get the `rowMeans`.  If the `ncol(b)` is te same as `length` of `c`, we `rbind` it.

Comment: the dimension of b is similar to that of c. dim of b is 1000 col * 500 row and dim of c is 1000 col * 500 row.

Comment: @temor Try `sapply(seq_len(ncol(b)), function(i) rowMeans(cbind(b[,i], c[,i]), na.rm=TRUE))`